# Android端末をFZ-B2からFZ－L1に変わったが、バーコードリーダの仕様が変わって実装方法が不明

Tags: android

表題の通りなのですが、新しく端末入れ替えるときにバーコードリーダの仕様が違っていて
現行が1文字ずつ読み込んでいるのに対し、新端末は一括で読み込んでいそうです。

新端末はSDKとかの情報があるのに対し、現行にはネット上にSDKの情報がなく、使っているのかすらもわからない状況です。

何かヒントやきっかけをご教授いただきたく質問をさせていただきました。

Androidバージョン：6.0→8.1

タフパッドFZ-B2 | パソコン（法人向け）| Panasonic
https://panasonic.biz/cns/pc/prod/pad/b2/

タフブックFZ-L1 | パソコン（法人向け）| Panasonic
https://panasonic.biz/cns/pc/prod/pad/l1/

皆様のお知恵を拝借させてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　質問なさりたい内容は、タフブックFZ-L1のバーコードリーダを使うSDKのドキュメントが知りたい、ということでしょうか？　それとも、タフパッドFZ-B2のバーコードリーダを使うSDKのドキュメントを知りたいということでしょうか。あるいはタフパッドFZ-B2用に書かれたソースコードをタフブックFZ-L1用に書き換える方法を知りたいのでしょうか（であれば現状のソースコードが無いと答えにくそうです）。

Comment: メーカー自身のサポート窓口以上に情報を持っているところはそうそう無いでしょう。[法人向けパソコンサポート|パナソニックパソコンサポート](https://askpc.panasonic.co.jp/s/)

Comment: @nekketsuuu 様
ありがとうございます。
確かにソースがなければ答えにくいですよね。
現状FZ-B2でSDKを使用せずにコードが書かれており、それをFZ-L1に書き換えることをしております。

Comment: @kunif 様
ありがとうございます。
確かにそうかも知れないですが下記のようなものは推奨されていないと思われるので、、、
現状FZ-B2でSDKを使用せずにコードが書かれており、それをFZ-L1に書き換えることをしております。

Comment: 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて情報を直接追記してください。 / まずは既存の FZ-B2 向けアプリ？をそのまま FZ-L1 で試すとどうなりますか？元々SDKを使っていなかったのなら、今回SDKの話が出てきたのはどういった経緯でですか？ / ネットにあまり情報が無いのも対象が法人向け端末だからだと思うので、当サイトの [ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) も参考に困りごとを整理してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

使える機能は機種によって若干違いがあるようですが、Panasonicが公開しているSDKではどちらの端末も共通してサポートしているように見えます。

[Download Panasonic Software Development Kit (SDK) for Android base models (V1.00L13M00)| Panasonic PC Support](https://pc-dl.panasonic.co.jp/dl/docs/074968?dc%5B%5D=002016&no=1&score=1.0&sri=14106608&trn_org=2)

バーコードリーダー向けに、ToughpadSDK に含まれる API の利用例を公開しているページがありました。

[Xamarin.AndroidでToughpadを使ってみる](http://www.shimizuya-sys.jp/archives/173)

Comment: 様 ありがとうございます。 
現状FZ-B2でSDKを使用せずにコードが書かれており、それをFZ-L1に書き換えることをしております。。。